# sendto batch script only allows 86 files?

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a batch script to grab filenames. I have a sendto script.
It works on groups of files less than 88 but not 88 or greater.
If I select 88+ files and use the right click sendto>myscript.bat I don't even get a command window.

```
@echo off
setlocal enable delayed expansion

set output="c:\temp\file.csv"

set file=%*

for %%F in (%file%) do (set fileList=!fileList!%%~npxF,)
echo %fileList% > %output%
```

I removed the path from the output list and that did not change the output.
I made the first command of the script a pause and didn't get a cmd window.

Comment: I believe the command line is getting longer than about 8190 characters, which is too much for `cmd.exe`…

Answer (score 2):

From Raymond Chen's OldNewThing blog [What is the command line length limit?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553) (**emphasis added**):

> It depends on whom you ask. The maximum command line length for the CreateProcess function is 32767 characters. This limitation comes from the UNICODE_STRING structure. CreateProcess is the core function for creating processes, so if you are talking directly to Win32, then that’s the only limit you have to worry about. But if you are reaching CreateProcess by some other means, then the path you travel through may have other limits. **If you are using the CMD.EXE command processor, then you are also subject to the 8192 character command line length limit imposed by CMD.EXE.** If you are using the ShellExecute/Ex function, then you become subject to the INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH (around 2048) command line length limit imposed by the ShellExecute/Ex functions. (If you are running on Windows 95, then the limit is only MAX_PATH.) While I’m here, I may as well mention another limit: The maximum size of your environment is 32767 characters. The size of the environment includes the all the variable names plus all the values.

Comment: There is something to that. I have another pile of files on another disk and for those files it's 85 files. I created a new set of files on C:\temp and there it's 100 files.